# Control another phone via bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, screen-mirroring

I need to control an android phone by another android phone using bluetooth.

Same as *Teamviewer*, but via bluetooth.

Suggestions ?

I have root and xposed.

So far I found only apps that use Wifi, or that transmit to a TV. Not what I need.

To make it more difficult: one of the devices is android 4.1

**Edit 1:** I said *mirror* before. It was wrong. I meant *control*. Need to view and control another device.

**Edit 2:** It may be something different than bluetooth, as long as no internet be required.

Comment: Bluetooth is too slow to transmit video data like it is needed for screen mirroring/sharing.

Comment: It's fast enough. There's an app called "Bluetooth Remote Camera" that I stumbled while looking for this. If it's that fast, then it's great.

Comment: Technically screen mirroring is very close to video streaming. See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414806/video-streaming-over-bluetooth

Comment: Thank you, Robert. I have edited the thread to correct my request. Even if the participants of your linked question had achieved a result, it wouldn't yet match my need.

Comment: Would a battery powered WiFi access point (i.e. a RaspberryPi) be acceptable to link the two Android phones?

Comment: Android has a Wifi mode called "Wi-Fi Direct" which allows to connect two Android devices without any need for a third device like an access point. You can check the screen mirroring apps if they support Wifi direct.

Comment: I found the WiFi Direct idea very interesting. But you yourself pointed out the main problem: a mirror (control) app that doesn't demand an external server. So far I found not such an app. I'm open to recommendations.

Comment: The WiFi AP is another idea, but I think it falls on the same problem as Robert's solution: no control apps that work over LAN exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

[RemoDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.im.RemoDroid) is the answer.

**Works through WiFi Direct.**

Works on older phones by using older versions  (0.15.4 worked on my 4.4.0, same version installed on both).

Not bluetooth, but works.

Thanks Robert for showing the way